# How to decode the json data from WHMCS and display the data using foreach loop in laravel-5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, whmcs

The controller code is given below:

```
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
 public function show(){

    $products = Whmcs::GetProducts([
        'pid'=>'pid',
        'name' =>'name',
        'price' =>'price',
        'description' =>'description'


    ]);

    return view('main.SME_Hosting',['products'=>$products]);


    }
}
```

The code using foreach is as follows:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
           {{$product}}



@endforeach
```

I'm getting an error as Expecting string not an array given.. and Undefined variable 'pid'.

The Route code is:

```
Route::get('SME_Hosting','GetProductController@show');
```

Suggest a solution to decode the json data and display it.

Comment: what you get if you add print_r($products); before return view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: 
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
 public function show(){

```
$products = Whmcs::GetProducts([
    'pid',
    'name',
    'price',
    'description'
]);

return view('main.SME_Hosting',['products'=>$products]);
}
```

And in view:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
       {{$product->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. But it's not working and again I'm getting error as: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.. Can you suggest me a solution to rectify this error.

Comment: can you please paste all output of $products variable.? I will help you out for this problem.